# Is the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality valid for the Lebesgue space $L^2(0,T,L^2(\Omega))$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded set. It is known that if $f, g \in L^2(\Omega)$ then by [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2) we have
$$
\Bigg| \int_{\Omega} f(x)\overline{g(x)}\; dx\Bigg|^2 \leq \int_{\Omega} |f(x)|^2 \cdot  \int_{\Omega} |g(x)|^2
$$

**Question.** For $T>0$, is an analogous result valid for the Lebesgue space $L^2(0,T,L^2(\Omega))$ ? That is, if $h \in L^2(0,T,L^2(\Omega))$ then
$$
\Bigg\|\int_0^t h(s) \; ds\Bigg\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \leq  c \cdot \int_0^t \|h(s)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \; ds, \: t \in (0,T)
$$
for some constant $c>0$?

I believe it is valid, but having little knowledge of these Lebesgue spaces $L^p(0,T, X)$, with $X$ a Banach Space, I was unable to prove. For more details of the this Lebesgue Spaces, see for instance the Eberhard Zeidler book's *Nonlinear Functional Analysis and Its Applications(2A)-Linear Monotone Operators* .

Comment: Yes. You can prove that $L^2(X, H)$ is a Hilbert space whenever $H$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for the first question, since $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ is a Hilbert space. For the second question, note that $\left\| \int_{0}^{t} h(s)ds\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \int_{0}^{t} \left\|h(s)\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}ds$ and $$\int_{0}^{t}\|h(s)\|_{L^2(\Omega}ds \leq \left( \int_{0}^{t}1^2ds \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \int_{0}^{t}\|h(s)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 ds\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$ Then,
$$\left\| \int_{0}^{t} h(s)ds\right\|^{2} \leq t \int_{0}^{t}\|h(s)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 ds.$$